# Save an image from a HTTP request in S3 using python lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to create a simple serverless function in AWS with a Gateway API that allows uploading an image to the server, it should then save the image in a S3 bucket.
This is my code:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    operation = event['httpMethod']
    if operation != 'PUT':
        return respond(ValueError('Unsupported method "{}"'.format(operation)))
        
    try:
        queryParameters = event['queryStringParameters']
        
        username = queryParameters['username']
        picturename = username + "_image"
        print("picture name: " + picturename)
        fileContent = event['body']
        print("body size: " + str(len(fileContent)))
        object = s3.Object('zoneuserimagesbucket', picturename)
        object.put(Body=fileContent)
        return respond(None, "OK")
```

The image being save is twice as big as the original and not the same as the original.. What I'm missing?

Comment: Might be useful: [Does AWS apigateway change http body? How can I stop it from doing this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59383951/174777)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a base64 encoded data in event.body.

There are two ways to overcome this situation.

## Option 1 (easy)

Check event.isBase64Encoded - if it's set to true, base64.decode event.content to get a bytes object to write to S3.

## Option 2 (needs config and time)

API Gateway could decode the data for you, if asked.
This has the benefit your lambda function will need less memory and time to run, which is great *in the long term*

Steps:

1 - Decide how you want API Gateway to encode binary data for you (base64, raw) etc. If you receive the data as you want, your lambda will need less memory and time to run.

2 - Decide the 'field' in the request where you want your data to come (instead of just ´event.body´).

3 - Verify you have in API Gateway a media encoding defined for the field you want. For images: image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif, etc.

3 - Check that you have the correct mediaHandling in the responseTemplate:

- CONVERT_TO_BINARY: Transcode it binary data if it's in base64.
- CONVERT_TO_TEXT: Transcode the data as base64.

Related documentation:

- See the [announce in the AWS blog post (https://aws.amazon.com/es/blogs/compute/binary-support-for-api-integrations-with-amazon-api-gateway/)
- and [AWS API Gateway Payload Encodings](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-payload-encodings.html).

Comment: Worked.
It's worth mentioning that saving the API is not enough, one needs to "Deploy API" as well... Doh.. :(